# Linq to Entities table joining / SQL table joins - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-entities

I have this table set up:

> **tblOne** - One/Unique records
>
> - personID (Primary Key)
> - fieldOne
>
> **tblTwo** - Many
>
> - personID (Foreign Key)
> - fieldTwo
> - ***otherID***
>
> **tblThree** - Many
>
> - personID (Foreign Key)
> - fieldThree
>
> **tblFour** - Many
>
> - personID (Foreign Key)
> - fieldFour

And this code in code-behind:

```
var tmp = textbox.Text;
var entity = new Entities();
var base = entity.tblTWO.Where(x => x.otherID == tmp)
                        .Select(x => new
                          {
                             otherID = tmp,
                             personID = x.personID,
                             fieldOne = x.tblONE.fieldOne
                            //Need fields from tblThree and tblFour
                          })
                        .ToList();
```

In theory, I want to be able to search on otherID and pull all related fields from all 4 tables.

So, if I am searching on otherID = 123 and that record's personID = 999, then I will pull all data from tblOne, tblTwo and tblThree for personID = 999.

I am using Linq to Entities in code-behind and have only gotten as far as searching tblTwo and getting associated fields from tblOne.  I then learned that I could follow a many-to-one route, but not the reverse (hence why I get stuck when I try to trail tblOne to tblThree or tblFour).

I am attempting to pull these fields and bind them to separate controls later to display the records in a web app (i.e., all unique records for Field 1 in a gridview).  Is Linq to Entities not the proper method?  Someone I know mentioned attempting SQL, but I'm not sure how to join all these tables properly to get what I need.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!! Thank you very much.  :)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you match the "OtherID" in table2, retrieve the PersonID.

and use that new PersonID variable to perform a Linq expression to retrieve the necesary data from the other tables (assuming they share the same PersonID, which is what it looks like from your SQL setup).

```
var pID = entity.tblTWO.Where(x => x.Other_ID == tmp).Select(x => x.personID).toString(); //This retrieves the personID from table2, which you will use to search the other tables
var list = entity."sometable".Where(y => y.personID == pID).Select("Data").toList();     //Using the above PersonID, you search any table you want for a match and retrieve any data you need using "Select"
```

EDIT:
If you are talking about table joins, refer to some SQL statements. Firstly you have to think whether you need to keep these tables separate or not, if each table contains similar info in accordance with each personID, i suggest joining the tables.

I am unclear what you are seeking?
in your code, the temp ID to search comes from a textbox.
so you take this user input, and first search table two for a matching otherID, after a match has been found, you now retrieve the personID form this table (which should be shared among every table) using this personID, you may now search the remaining table and pull the data and store them however you need.

Comment: How do I join the "personID matched data" to the "otherID matched data"? I also need the fields from tblTwo (where otherID is), and I need each record for otherID to have all the associated personID info (if that makes sense).  So a table join, I guess...?  (Sorry, completely new here.  Thanks for the help, though!)

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity.  When I use Linq, tblOne has a one-to-many relationship with the other tables.  So, in using your recommendation, when I attempt to do... for example: `var list = blahblah.Select(x => new {fieldFour = x.tblFour.fieldFour}).ToList();`

It cannot identify fieldFour from tblFour.  None of tblFour's fields show up in intellisense.  Does that make sense?  So I can't select those fields using Linq.

Comment: yes you are right that table1 has the one-to-many relationship.
when using Linq, you should be able to see x.tblFour."dataInTblfour".

ensure you are not choosing the actual "int" key value from the foreign key, but that you are actually selecting the entire object.

Comment: I know that when i was using VS2013, some of the intellisense was not working. You may want to update your IDE to the latest version, and ensure that intellisense is enable

Comment: I know it works, here is an example from one of my projects, where Status1 is a table, but Tasks has a foreign key reference to the ID of the Status table. You also see how i retrieve the name of the Status using the one-to-many relationship.

`viewModel.Tasks = db.Tasks.Where(s => s.Status1.Name == "Open").ToList();`

Comment: So, if I have... `var list = entity.tblTwo.blahblah.Select( x => new Model {Test = x.tblOne.tblThree."data"}).ToList();` - should that "data" show up?

Comment: umm in theory, it should show up. I am unsure though.
it is because you first retrieve table1 through table2 then try to access table3 (which I have never done).

if for some reason this is not working, you should do my proposed solution of retrieving the personId and searching the various tables using that. Rather then trying to hop around.

Answer (score 0):

According to you table details, since tblThree and tblFour are 1-To-Many to tblOne, the fields in those tables are collections not a single entity, there are different ways to access them:

The way you have it detailed it looks like it should be a collection:

```
.Select(x => new
{
    MyCollection = x.tblOne.tblThree.Select(t=> new MyObject(t)).ToArray()
}
```

If you just get the first value (note if personID not in tblThree this would fail):

```
.Select(x => new
{
    firstFieldThree = x.tblOne.tblThree.First().fieldThree
}
```

If there is truly one value in tblThree and tblFour then personID should be a primary and foreign key then you would be able to access them like this:

```
.Select(x => new
{
    fieldThree = x.tblOne.tblThree.fieldThree
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join all your tables together. Use `DefaultIfEmpty` if you want a `left join`. You can use the entity 1 navigation property like this:

```
var base = from t1 in entity.t1
           from t2 in t1.t2.DefaultIfEmpty()
           from t3 in t1.t3.DefaultIfEmpty()
           from t4 in t1.t4.DefaultIfEmpty()
           where t2,otherID == tmp
           select new
           {
             otherID = tmp,
             t2.personID,
             t1.fieldOne,
             t3.fieldThree,
             t4.fieldFour
           };
```

Comment: Thank you!! This was exactly what I needed.  :) :)  I have an additional question, though. Say table t4 has a field called City, and the values are numbered IDs for a separate table (tblCities) with the actual city names. How would I do a join into that to retrieve the city names?  (Thank you so much for your help!!)

Comment: Annnd, ok. I was able to bring up the fields for the different tables in code, but when I went to bind the data to my controls, the data didn't come up.  Will continue to research/debug. :')

Comment: @Noobody Maybe you need to do a left join. I added the `DefaultIfEmpty`, maybe that will help

Answer (score 0):

```
var base = entity.tblTwo.Where(x => x.otherID == temp)
            .Select(x => new
            {
                OtherId = temp,
                PersonId= x.personID,
                FieldOne = x.tblOne.fieldOne,
                FieldThree = x.tblOne.tblThree.fieldThree,
                FieldFour = x.tblOne.tblFour.fieldFour
            }).ToList();
```

Also you can join four tables-

```
var base = (from t1 in entity.tblOne
                     join t2 in entity.tblTwo on t1.personID equals t2.personID
                     join t3 in entity.tblThree on t1.personID equals t3.personID
                     join t4 in entity.tblFour on t1.personID equals t4.personID
                     where t2.otherID == temp
                     select new{
                         OtherId = temp,
                         PersonId = t1.personID,
                         FieldOne = t1.fieldOne,
                         FieldThree = t3.fieldThree,
                         FieldFour = t4.fieldFour
                     }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! Quick question - if there is no matching personID data in, say, t4... will this query be null?  I guess I'm asking... does this need to have a personID match in all tables to work?

Comment: Sorry for late response. Yes personID needs to be matched in four tables. If not matched result will be null.